# Get source app URL from where API is being called it dot net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am working on Dot Net Core MVC API Project where I need to implement conditions based on from where request is coming. There are multiple apps utilizing my API and based on this condition, I want to modify response of the API.

Is there a simple way in .NET to quickly get the source app URL based on which I can base my condition.

For example, if request is coming from this app:

http://www.mywebsite.com:5000/

I need to return:

http://www.mywebsite.com:5000/

and if request is coming from this app

http://www.mywebsite.com:5005/

I need to return:

http://www.mywebsite.com:5005/

Any suggestions?

Comment: If u use Azure u can take advantage of API Management solution and you don't have to change your code.

Comment: HTTP requests don't come from URLs; they come from IP addresses, which can easily be spoofed, so using request address as a criterion is in general unsafe.